# How to use bootstrap collapse for particular value using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown:-

```
<select class="form-control" id="IDSelector">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
</select>                 

    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <input type="checkbox" id="select" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1"> Please Select
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          </div>
          <div class="panel-footer">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to do is when I select `B` from dropdown my panel get collapsed else not.

But I am not sure how to do it with javascript

Answer (score 2):

Try this inside document.ready

```
  $( "#IDSelector" ).change(function() {
    if($( "#IDSelector" ).val() == "B"){
      $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
    else{
          $('.collapse').collapse('show');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically must listen for the onChange event on the select tag. If its value is 'B', then you implement your special behavior (like collapsing another part of the DOM).

EDIT:

```
function handleChange(event) {
  var panGroup = document.querySelector('.panel-group');

  //This code hides or displays the panel but you can do whatever you like.
  if(event.target.value === 'B') {
    panGroup.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    panGroup.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

And

```
<select class="form-control" id="IDSelector" onchange="handleChange(event)">
```

Hope this helps.